# How do I add jQuery function to Admin LTE 2 template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using Admin LTE 2 template for my project, and now I want to add a jQuery to some of my controls, on its documentation it says that its main javascript file is the **app.js** so I tried adding a jQuery function on it but it doesn't work, and I'm looking for the `jQuery(document).ready` but it's not on the app.js. So I added my own javascript file but it still didn't work on my textbox but on my other project, the javascript I added works well. Does this mean that my javascript file is being overridden by the app.js?

Does anyone knows how to add jQuery function along with Admin LTE 2 template? The following are the simple codes I added:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStartDate").datepicker();
    });
});
```

Just to make things clear again, this works on my other project, but on this current project I'm working on, it's not working, I'm not sure why, that's why I'm here asking.

P.S. I'm using ASP.Net Master Page / Web Forms that's why the **id** is like that.

Comment: Is this the exact code you have, without <script> tags along the snippet?

Comment: the jQuery is in a separate file and being called to html by <script type="text/javascript"  src="main.js"></script>